# Harshad number in python without statements (if, else, while, for)

Tags: python

I need to find a way to split a string of multiples numbers into multiples strings of those numbers and then split again to have individual digits which would allow me to test those first inputed numbers to see if they are a harshad number without using for, else, while and if.

So far i'm able to split the input string:

a = input("Multiple numbers separated by a ,: ")

a.split(",")

Then I need to split again I think I need to use the map function. Any idea how to go any further.

Comment: Can you share what have you tried?

Comment: if and else are not loops. Are you forbidden to use loops, or are you forbidden to use if statements?

Comment: I can't use if, for, while, else.

Comment: ```map(list, a.split(","))``` should get you started. Can you rephrase the question without the use of "if"?

Answer (score 0):

The python *builtin* functions **map**, **filter**, and **reduce** are going to be your friend when you are working in a more functional style.

#### map

The `map` function lets you transform each item in an iterable (list, tuple, etc.) by passing it to a function and using the return value as a new value in a new iteratable*.
The non-functional approach would use a `for ... in` construct:

```py
numbers_as_strings = ["1", "12", "13"]
numbers_as_ints = []
for number in numbers_as_strings:
  numbers_as_ints.append(int(number))
```

or more concisely a list comprehension

```py
numbers_as_ints =[int(number) for number in numbers_as_strings]
```

Since you are eschewing `for` there is another way

```py
numbers_as_ints = map(int, numbers_as_strings)
```

But you don't just want your strings mapped to integers, you want to test them for harshadiness. Since we're doing the functional thing let's create a function to do this for us.

```py
def is_harshad(number_as_string):
  return # do your harshad test here
```

Then you can map your numbers through this function

```py
list(map(is_harshad, numbers_as_string))  # wrap in list() to resolve the returned map object.
>>> [True, True, False]
```

But maybe you want the results as a sequence of harshady number strings? Well check out **filter**

#### filter

The `filter` function lets you choose which items from an iterable you want to keep in a new iterable. You give it a function that operates on an single item and returns True for a keeper or False for a rejection. You also give it an iterable of items to test.

A non-functional way to do this is with a for loop

```py
harshady_numbers = []
for number in numbers_as_strings:
  if is_harshad(number):
    harshady_numbers.append(number)
```

Or more concisely and nicely, with a list comprehension

```py
harshady_numbers = [number for number in numbers_as_strings if is_harshady(number)]
```

But, since we're getting functional well use `filter`

```py
harshady_numbers = filter(is_harshady, numbers_as_strings)
```

That's about it. Apply the same functional thinking to complete the `is_harshad` function and you're done.

- - [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) can take more than one iterable argument and it returns an iterator not a list.